# Clarification of NHS Surcharge (UK Tiered Applicants)

Tags: united-kingdom, nhs

Recent changes in the immigration rules require that some visa applicants must pay a surcharge for the National Health Service (NHS).  This question is about applicants in the Tiered category.

For a Tier 1 (Investor) applying to extend their status (as opposed to an applicant switching into this category), the charge should be £400 (£200 per year x 2 year grant). A Tier 1 (Investor) extension can only be granted for a period of 2 years.

However, the drop-down options online state that the charge will be £600 for a Tier 1 (Investor) leave to remain, regardless of whether the applicant is applying for an extension (2 years) or an initial grant of leave by switching to this category (3 years).  There is no option to pay £200.

The surcharge must be paid in full for the entire term of the visa at the time the application is submitted.

Which of these is the applicant for T1 extension required to pay?

Adding: access to the form is at https://www.gov.uk/healthcare-immigration-application/pay, you'll need to register to start (which you can cancel before adding your credit card details)

Adding: the guidance itself starts at https://www.gov.uk/healthcare-immigration-application/overview  and the Home Office press release is at https://www.gov.uk/government/news/uk-introduces-health-surcharge

Comment: The fee is relatively new and the number of Tier 1 extensions is potentially so small that you might be the first person to have used that part of the online form. It could be a bug.

Comment: @StrongBad, that might work for an answer.

Comment: I would rather someone email UKVI and ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly point out, while a Tier 1 extension may be granted for two years in certain instances, logically the amount should be £400 total (£200 per year), not £600.

Subsequent to 6 April 2015, when the NHS surcharge came into effect for non-EEA nationals making UK visa applications, UKVI introduced a new tool to [Calculate your immigration health surcharge](https://www.immigration-health-surcharge.service.gov.uk/checker/type)  which appears to address that issue.

[Tier 1 (Entrepreneur) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/extend-your-visa) guidance on how to extend also points to the calculator.

> You can [apply to extend](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/extend-your-visa) this visa for another 2 years if you’re already in this category and 3 years if you’re [switching](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/switch-to-this-visa) to it from another category.
>
> [Extend your visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/extend-your-visa)
>   You’ll also have to [pay the healthcare surcharge](https://www.gov.uk/healthcare-immigration-application/pay) as part of your application. Check how much you’ll have to pay [before you apply](https://www.immigration-health-surcharge.service.gov.uk/checker/type).

After initial selections (currently in the UK, visa type Tier 1), you are able to select visa route from among the following:

- Tier 1 Entrepreneur **[£1000]**
- Tier 1 (Investor) **[£600]**
- Tier 1 (Exceptional Talent) visa **[£1000]**
- Tier 1 (Graduate Entrepreneur) visa **[£200]**
- Tier 1 (Exceptional Talent) visa 1 year **[£200]**
- Tier 1 (Exceptional Talent) visa 2 year **[£400]**
- Tier 1 (Exceptional Talent) visa 3 year **[£600]**
- Tier 1 (Exceptional Talent) visa 4 year **[£800]**
- Tier 1 (Exceptional Talent) visa 5 year **[£1000]**

The above results, as noted in bold, are based on one individual, already in the UK on a Tier 1 visa. How much will vary, depending on type and length of leave and where application is made, and must be paid in advance by all applicants, including each family member.